# android foreign key. program crashes

Tags: android

```
public static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TASK = "task";
public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
public static final String COLUMN_INITDATE = "initdate";
public static final String COLUMN_PRIORITY="priority";

public static final String TABLE_REPEAT = "alarms";
public static final String COLUMN_AID = "_aid";
public static final String COLUMN_TID = "tid";
```

public static final String COLUMN_DAYS= "days";

```
private static final String DATABASE1_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
+ COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+ COLUMN_TASK
+ " text not null, "+ COLUMN_TIME+" integer not null, "+ COLUMN_INITDATE+" integer not null, "+ COLUMN_PRIORITY +" integer );";

private static final String DATABASE2_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_REPEAT + "("
        + COLUMN_AID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+  " FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_TID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_TASKS + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " ), "+ COLUMN_DAYS + " text not null );";
```

my logcat is as:
03-06 09:17:07.051: E/AndroidRuntime(1029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.habitator/com.example.habitator.Habitator}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "tid" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: create table alarms(_aid integer primary key autoincrement,  FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES tasks ( _id ), days text not null );

pls help me find the error!! why doe my prgram crash??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this query.

```
create table alarms(_aid integer primary key autoincrement, tid integer FOREIGNKEY REFERENCES tasks ( _id ), days text not null );
```

https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: I was doing it wrong as well. I used FOREIGN KEY (payment_method) REFERENCES payment_method(id) but i was consonantly getting an error "unknown column payment_method in foreign key definition (code 1):"   .... I ended up using payment_method INTEGER FOREIGNKEY REFERENCES payment_method(id) and it worked perfectly.